# Detect back button press to conditionally render page with html5 session storage state

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am using html5 session storage to store state of a dynamic page.

If my page is loaded via a bookmark, inbound link, page refresh, or pressing "enter" in the address bar, html5 session storage should be reset. (case a)

If my page is loaded via back button, the session storage should not be reset and should be used to render the page with state. (case b)

How can I use JavaScript to discern case a from case b so I can conditionally reset the state?

(I am implementing functionality similar to google maps search results.)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: One idea: The server creates a timestamp value that gets assigned to a JavaScript variable when the page loads. We save this variable in the html5 session storage, but we check… if the same value is already in the session storage we know are pulling the page from cache (back button), and if it is not already in the session storage we are doing a fresh page load.

This feels like a hack, and I'm not sure whether this will meet my use cases because I am not sure how different browsers may treat caching.

Comment: Maybe better idea: Using HTML5 history, which is probably what I'm going to end up doing